# javascript - How do I perform await operation as while conditions or equivalence for it?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, windows-runtime

I've been working with SQLiteWinRT library and there's no way I can't implement (the far I know) the equivalence of async operation working in bucles for javascript.
Here is an example:

```
await db.OpenAsync(SQLiteWinRT.SqliteOpenMode.OpenRead);
var stmt = await db.PrepareStatementAsync(
    "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'"
);
//this is the part
while ( await stmt.StepAsync() )
{
    string table = stmt.GetTextAt(0);
    this.ViewModel.DatabaseTables.Add(table);
}
```

I hope to be doing the right question.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution by myself . I hope this can help someone

```
var arr = [];//stmt is IAsyncOperation<Statement> result, that is, Statement instance result;

stmt.stepAsync().then(function (r) {
    if (r) {
        var obj = {}, i = -1;
        while (++i &lt; stmt.columnCount) {
            obj[stmt.getColumnName(i)] = stmt.getTextAt(i);
        }
        arr.push(obj);
        stmt.stepAsync().then(arguments.callee);
    } else {
        console.log(arr);
    }
});
```